# Adjectival form of "advocate"?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

What's a good adjective that means something similar to "advocate"?  For instance, "He is an advocate.  He's _____."

Proactive and practical are not quite the right sense -- proactive ignores the spokesman aspect, and practical ignores the vocal aspect.

Does English have any adjectives that express the same idea as "advocate"?

Comment: How 'bout *evangelistic*

Comment: _Evangelist(ic)_ has a negative connotation that _advocate_ (and its synonyms like _champion_) don't share.

Comment: I guess it depends on what context.  In the software world a software evangelist has no negative connotations that I know of. And since *any* English word can be given a negative bent simply by the tone of voice it's spoken with, I don't know that anyone will be able to provide a truly positive word.

Comment: Hm.  I find "software evangelist" to indicate zealotry and substantial bias, not neutral affect.  You've uncovered for me that *I* am the one who finds such bias a negative, though.  Perhaps a better way to express this is that "advocate" also suggests a level of neutrality or non-emotionality that I'm not finding in any possible synonyms.  I'm coming to the conclusion that an adjective that hits the idea of "vocal about support for something, not relying on emotional resonance" doesn't actually exist (unless one resorts to adjectives awkwardly built from the root).

Comment: Did you just sneak in "neutral effect"?  I don't think an advocate is neutral- they are biased toward whatever they're advocating- or they wouldn't be advocating it.

Comment: [From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_evangelist): *A technology evangelist is a person who builds a critical mass of support for a given technology, and then establishes it as a technical standard in a market that is subject to network effects.[1] An evangelist promotes the use of a particular product or technology through talks, articles, blogging, user demonstrations, recorded demonstrations, or the creation of sample projects.*  I think that's a pretty positive thing and brings in your ideas of  spokesperson and vocal aspect.

Comment: Neutral affect, not effect -- emotional neutrality.  Evangelism is about being hooked emotionally on whatever is being sold.  It conveys a level of passion and fervent belief in the thing that's being advocated for.  Advocacy is not fervent -- it tries to come from "thinking" rather than "feeling".  (And I'd argue that this is why you see techie crowds liking the word "evangelism" -- it conveys a sense of emotion that techies aren't stereotyped to have -- and it's why you see fields like education and non-profits liking the word "advocacy" -- it busts their stereotype the other direction.)

Answer (score 1):

Advocatory should be good enough for an adjective.  Meaning does say 'characteristic of an advocate'.

Comment: Probably *advocatorial* is what fits in OP's fill-in-the-blank.

Comment: True, but neither is used in common English.

Comment: I woulda said "advocative".

Answer (score 1):

According to [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/advocate) the adj form for Advocate is Advocative.

> **advocate**
>   RELATED FORMS
>   ad·vo·ca·tive , adjective
>   ad·vo·ca·tor , noun
>   non·ad·vo·cate , noun
>   pre·ad·vo·cate , noun

Comment: This is the beginning of a good answer. It would be best to link to the source and then cite the relative information in a block quote.

Comment: Your effort is appreciated. A new and relevant response to an old question is always delightful to see. Note that a Stack Exchange answer is lengthy enough to show that it is right. It gives explanation and context. Also, like schools and journals, Stack Exchange does not allow users to earn reputation from the works of others. Answers should be your own. An answer which is not much more than a link to an answer elsewhere may be deleted.

Comment: I was just going to suggest this as a made-up word for this.  Turns out it was not made up by me.  I adjusted the answer as suggested last year.  As long as plt does not return and select an answer (unlikely, since he has not been here for 4 years now), this question will keep coinmg back to the front page.